# How do Excel VBA Number format options work for users with different regional settings?

Tags: excel, vba

I would like a number to show only 2 decimal places behind the comma (or point). I found that i can do that by specifying `someRange.NumberFormat = "#.##"`, but how will this work if a user has set a comma as a decimal separator?

Comment: I think it would be fine. It would only be potentially problematic if `someRange.NumberFormatLocal` was used.

Comment: Albeit I've never personally used a non-American version of VBA, I have used `Application.ThousandSeparator = ","`
and `Application.DecimalSeparator  = "."` within the preceding code in hopes that I would not negatively affect someone... so far I haven't had a complaint?

Comment: Add Application.DecimalSeparator  = "," and run your code to test

Comment: Use this: `someRange.NumberFormat = "#" & Application.DecimalSeparator & "##"`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When setting `NumberFormat`, the US English format string should be entered - i.e. `"#.##"`. That is to say, regardless of the `.DecimalSeparator` set by the user/environment, the format string requires a period (`.`) to denote the decimal separator.

```
someRange.NumberFormat = "#.##"
```

The above would be safe to run regardless of the users locale settings or `.DecimalSeparator` set by the user.

If you'd prefer to set it using an alternative language/locale format string e.g. German, then you need to tell Excel you're giving it the locale appropriate format - however, you'd need to test the locale settings beforehand to ensure it was going to work - in case the program is not being run with that locale setting:

```
someRange.NumberFormatLocal = "#,##"
```

I can't think of a good reason why you'd want to do it that way, unless you were only sure of the e.g. German format string. If that's the case, then you could check what it is in US English by reading the non-local property:

```
someRange.NumberFormatLocal = "#,##"
debug.print someRange.NumberFormat
```

Output:

```
#.##
```

Comment: Thank you for the answer, this is exactly what I need. I am having some trouble verifying the first part though, I can't find anything in the documentation. Do you happen to know if it is written anywhere that the format string should always be in US format?

Comment: Sorry, no - I'm not aware of anything directly from Microsoft. It seems to be all anecdotal advice when looking at other support sites such as S.O. and alternatives.

Comment: I did find this article: http://www.oaltd.co.uk/ExcelProgRef/Ch22/ProgRefCh22.htm. Unfortunately I don't have much time to test it thoroughly, but your answer looks correct to me (for whatever that means). I'll upvote and accept. Thanks!